# Excel filtering for merged cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to make a calculation of hours worked for each employee on each project that he worked on. But i don't know how to select because the cells that are containing the name of the employee are merged like in the picture. And if i want to see on project no. 3 which are the employees that worked on, the Excel Filtering can't take the name "John" which corresponds only to project no.1. To be more clear, I need to know how the filtering will be made for cells A3 and A4.
If i will unmerge the cells, John will be only on cell A2, and in fact he worked also on projects 2 & 3.

Thanks!

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: And it isn't possible to just once unmerge everything and copy "John" to the respective cells? Not a pretty solution, but very easy. Merged Cells are evil - get rid of it

Comment: It is not possible because in the original Excel there are thousands of Employees and Projects :( it will take forever to do this...every week..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a Merged Cell, and you attempt to Filter for it, you will only get the first row:
[image: Rows with Merged Cells]
[image: Filtered Merged Cells only shows first row]

To fix this, you first need to start by creating your Merged Cells somewhere else, unmerge your filter-cells, and fill the values into all cells:
[image: Table cells unmerged, merged cells on right]

Then, you can Copy the merged cells, and Paste Special > Formats over the cells you *want* to merge:
[image: Copying the Merged Cells and using Paste Special to put format in data table]
[image: The Merged Cell formatting pasted in place]

You can now delete your temporary merged cells, and when you filter you will get **all** rows for the merged cell:
[image]

**{EDIT}** *Here is a macro that will automatically apply the changes above to a specified range:*

```vb
Public Sub FilterableMergedCells()
    Dim WorkingRange As Range
SelectRange:
    Set WorkingRange = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkingRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    'If you click Cancel
    If WorkingRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'If you select multiple Ranges
    If WorkingRange.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select 1 continuous range only", vbCritical
        GoTo SelectRange
    End If

    Dim ScreenUpdating As Boolean, DisplayAlerts As Boolean, Calculation As XlCalculation
    ScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    DisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Calculation = Application.Calculation

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim WorkingCell As Range, MergeCell As Range, MergeRange As Range, OffsetX As Long, OffsetY As Long
    OffsetX = WorkingRange.Cells(1, 1).Column - 1
    OffsetY = WorkingRange.Cells(1, 1).Row - 1
    'Create temporary sheet to work with
    With Worksheets.Add
        WorkingRange.Copy .Cells(1, 1)
        'Loop through cells in Range
        For Each WorkingCell In WorkingRange.Cells
            'If is a merged cell
            If WorkingCell.MergeCells Then
                'If is the top/left merged cell in a range
                If Not Intersect(WorkingCell, WorkingCell.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)) Is Nothing Then
                    Set MergeRange = WorkingCell.MergeArea
                    'Unmerge cells
                    MergeRange.MergeCells = False
                    'Replicate value to all cells in formerly merged area
                    For Each MergeCell In MergeRange.Cells
                        If WorkingCell.FormulaArray = vbNull Then
                            MergeCell.Formula = WorkingCell.Formula
                        Else
                            MergeCell.FormulaArray = WorkingCell.FormulaArray
                        End If
                    Next MergeCell
                    'Copy merge-formatting over old Merged area
                    .Cells(WorkingCell.Row - OffsetY, WorkingCell.Column - OffsetX).MergeArea.Copy
                    WorkingCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                End If
            End If
        Next WorkingCell
        .Delete
    End With

    Set MergeRange = Nothing
    Set WorkingRange = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdating
    Application.DisplayAlerts = DisplayAlerts
    Application.Calculation = Calculation
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this solution will take too much time for what I need

Comment: @AndreeaDanaEnache Added a VBA macro to go through and do all the hard-work for you.  (Programmers are "efficient", not "lazy" - honest!)

Comment: @Chronocidal I want to use your script, but it bugs out on me at line 42 with "object not found". Do you know why this is?

Comment: @RyzaJr. I have tracked this down to a change in how `Null` values are handled in newer versions of Excel, and updated the code to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

One other option;

Conditional formatting background for all cells with a particular value (e.g. John, red background) and then filter by colour.

Wouldn't suit all applications but nice and quick.

Answer (score 0):

The green tick answer by Chronocidal requires use of Macro.
Personally, I don't think it is necessary to go through such cumbersome process.

Suppose merged cells are in Column A; first merged data is in cell A2.
Make a new column on the right of merged cell column [B Column].
In the cell B2, type =IF(LEN(A2)=0,B1,A2) and drag this formula down.
It will fill data correctly and you can apply filter on column B.

Note: Formula checks length of characters of left cell. If it is zero, uses cell directly above as answer; otherwise uses left cell as is.

[Excel Snapshot of Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv46S.png)