# Excel Filter is not working for Merged Cells

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgFk1.png)I have 3 rows(Merged) with the text "Covered" and 4 rows(Un-merged) with the text "ABC".
I applied a text filter - Does not contains - "Covered"

I expected to see just 4 rows which have the text "ABC" but i am still getting 2 rows which contains "Covered".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel filtering for merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816515/excel-filtering-for-merged-cells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually... you filter works just fine.. the "Covered in B" text is Actually stored in B4 and B5 cell is actually empty ( you can test this using =B5 anywhere in the sheet. ) A merged cell (in this case B5) only 'shows' the content of its 1st cell(B4). but it's actual cell value is a blank.