# Pandas filtering of merged cells

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of this format

[image]

When I export it to excel and use filters on the basis of SITE-ID, it will only show the first row of that group. For example

[image]

I do understand, that's how excel works and there are alternatives to this from within excel.
But is there something I could do to solve this problem from within pandas when it exports to excel so that when I filter on Site-ID, I will see everything under that Site-ID? I don't want to do any VBA or macros for this.

Thanks

Comment: Filter and merged cells don't work together. You'll need each data element repeated row-by-row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are agree to lose the merge, you can try

```
df.to_excel('filename', merge_cells=False)
```

Else, You can try to reset_index of your data frame before exporting.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.to_excel('filename', index=False )
```

Or you want to keep others columns merged (because you will not use filters you can reset only index on site-id:

```
df.reset_index('SITE-ID', inplace=True)
df.to_excel('filename' )
```

Else you have the only solution is the workaround:
[Excel filtering for merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49816515/12744275)
But I don't think that you are agree with that

Comment: I have tried doing all of the above solutions already before posting but the there is an issue with every method.

1. removes merge that i want to keep
2. doesn't give me the nicely formatted output as merge gives
3. This is what i want but i want the site-id column to be the first one. Is there a way you can append a column in front of index columns so that index columns preserve the formatting but still able to add "Site-ID" as first column as a non index column. Or even if site-id is an index column, i don't want it to get merged but the following columns should still retain merge?

Comment: I fortunately, I don't think than it is possible to put a non index column before indexes. The best I can submit you is to create a normal column which is a copy of SITE-ID index with:
df.assign(SITE-ID_copy=df.index.get_level_values('SITE-ID'))