# Is there a way to make merged cells filterable in excel using Openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I was looking for a way to make merged cells filterable using openpyxl.

E.g Filtering on first name "John" in the below workbook:

[image: Workbook]

Should return the first three rows:
[image: Desired Filter Behavior]
Rather than returning only the top row (the default excel behavior):
[image: Default Excel Behavior]

The problem is that by default merged ranges only contain a value in the top left cell of the range:
[Default merged cell values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhbDV.png)

Using openpyxl is it possible to overwrite the None values within merged cells effectively making them filterable?
[Desired Merged cell values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHYOm.png)

For reference, you can already create filterable merged cells using macros or manual formatting as per the answer here: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/49817670/14251756**

I've already tried overwriting the none values using the below script but get the error *AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only*

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Workbook")
ws = wb['Worksheet']

#Get list of ranges of merged cells
merged_cell_ranges = ws.merged_cells.ranges
merged_cell_ranges = list(map(str,merged_cell_ranges))

#Iterate through ranges and write top merged cell value to empty cells
for merged_range in merged_cell_ranges:
    for row in ws[merged_range]:
        for cell in row:
            cell.value = ws[merged_range.split(':')[0]].value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Far from ideal, but I achieved the desired result by modifying the openpyxl source.

The function to modify is located here:
https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.0/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py#L586

you can simply add an argument to choose whether or not the cells become merged cells and therefor "cleaned".

The modified function now looks like this:

```
    def merge_cells(self, range_string=None, start_row=None, start_column=None, end_row=None, end_column=None, clean=True):
        """ Set merge on a cell range.  Range is a cell range (e.g. A1:E1) """
        if range_string is None:
            cr = CellRange(range_string=range_string, min_col=start_column, min_row=start_row,
                      max_col=end_column, max_row=end_row)
            range_string = cr.coord
        mcr = MergedCellRange(self, range_string)
        self.merged_cells.add(mcr)
        if clean:
            self._clean_merge_range(mcr)
        else:
            mcr.format()
```

Simply add clean=False to keep the values.

```
ws.merge_cells('A2:A9', clean=False)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks very much for your response.