# Excel Function - Return Value with Merge Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm currently working on Excel, and I used the Index function. However, since I wanted to return value, it can't return the cell with merge cell where it is intended for what I look for or return for.

I am currently using this formula just like in the 2nd picture.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('General Journal'!D6:D11,SMALL(IF('General Journal'!C6:C11=B2,ROW('General Journal'!C6:C11)-5,""),ROW('General Journal'!C6:C11)-5)),"")
```

At the first date, it was successful because it just read the first cell in a 2 merge cell. However, in second and third, it was returned "0" because it is a merge cell and the value was like in the second cell. What formula could I still use even though it is in a merge cell? Thank you!

[image: 2nd Picture]

[image: 1st Picture]

Comment: Simplict would be a Helper column "General Journal" with a formula that repeats the values from the merged cells, and refer to that in your other formula

Comment: @chrisneilsen hi! thank you for replying. I do apologize, but what do you mean by the simplict?

Comment: Oops, spelling.  Meant "Simplest" as in I can't think of a simpler way

Comment: I believe that [this fix for Merge Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816515/excel-filtering-for-merged-cells/49817670#49817670) should also work in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

[image: FILTER function]

If you are using Office365 try something like this

```
=FILTER(FILTER(B5:D11,D5:D11<>""),{1,0,1})
```